# Solution to equation with moore-penrose inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, inverse, pseudoinverse

I have a linear equation of the form

$$
C = (I-AA^+)X
$$

where my variable is $X$ and $A$ is an hermitian operator and $A^+$ is the pseudo inverse. Assuming that the determinant of $A$ is $0$ (or simply that there is a $0$ eigenvalues, then $A^+\neq A^{-1}$. In this case, can we say that a solution of this equation exists always? If no, what are the conditions to be fulfilled such that a solution exists?

Another question is if the answers to these questions change if the space is of finite dimensional matrix or is infinite dimensional.

Comment: By realizing that $I-AA^{\dagger}$ is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto $\left(\text{Col}(A)\right)^{\perp}$ you can say $(I-AA^{\dagger})X=C$ has a solution (for $X$) if and only if $\text{Col}(C)\subseteq \left(\text{Col}(A)\right)^{\perp}$.

Comment: @MatthewH. by Col()⊆(Col())⊥ what do you mean exactly?